# Which is correct: "A is higher as compared that" OR "A is high as compared to"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, comparatives

- The weight of A is **higher** as compared that of its counterparts.
- The weight of A is **high** as compared to that of its counterparts.

Which word is more suitable —'high' or 'higher'?

Comment: Hi Rahul!  Sanskrit is incredibly precise, but English is a mess :)  You have to figure out "exactly what you mean" before trying to say it in English.  And then, you only have 30% chance of success :-)

Comment: "A is heavier than..." would be more natural.

Comment: Another "hit & run" user. (Posts and then runs away)

Answer (score 3):

I don't like Joe's answer for two reasons. First,  "The weight of A is high, compared to its counterparts." begs what the absolute magnitude should be for this to be used, i.e., at what point is the weight of something "high". Second, high usually describes height; and heavy describes weight. It doesn't make sense to say "it weighs higher" or anything like that because we are talking about weight not height. Something is *heavier* or *weighs more*.

The best, in my opinion, would be:

> A weighs more than its counterparts.

Or

> A is heavier than its counterparts.

I prefer the first slightly more because I (as a reader) have to do a lookup in my brain for the phrase "is heavier" which will return "weighs more than".

Answer (score -1):

Both your sentences are no-good, but these are ok:

> The weight of A is high, compared to its counterparts.

or

> The weight of A is higher than all of its counterparts.

NOTE THAT they mean different things!  Hope it helps!

Comment: But as Roaring Fish says, it is very odd to talk about the weight being "high". You could say _the weight is greater than all of its counterparts_, (but probably not _the weight is great, compared to ..._); but much more natural is _A is heavy, compared to ..._ or _A is heavier than ..._